# Xbox controller battery doesnt charge

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [360 controller battery doesn’t hold charge after unplugging Play & Charge Kit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86343/360-controller-battery-doesnt-hold-charge-after-unplugging-play-charge-kit)

My Xbox controller battery doesn't charge.

When I plug it in, the indicator light immediately goes from red to green.

Is their any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the paperclip reset method?

These things usually break for two reasons.

1. The battery is improperly conditioned.
2. The Charging level indicator has failed.

Either way, this video has a solution for both.

It involves a series of pins to short using a paperclip.

Comment: It Worked!!! You sir, are a scholar.